# Ember.js: Get url string to a model instance using its route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a `Book` model instance and would like to get a `href` string to it given its route. Eg:

`someEmberJSMethod('book.edit', aBookInstance) #=> "/books/12/edit"`

Given the route:

```
@resource "books", ->
    @route "edit", path: "/:book_id/edit"
```

I tried looking at the Ember.js source and how `link-to` helper generates the `href` given the route name and the instance, but didn't manage to find the answer.

Comment: @KalmanHazins, as I understand `transitionTo()` actually redirects you to the new route, but doesn't return the url it is going to redirect you to (e.g. `"/books/12"`). I simply need that url string.

Comment: yea, I misunderstood the question - sorry about that... Comment deleted

Comment: @KalmanHazins, actually I also made a mistake, I meant to get `/books/12/edit` string instead of `/books/12`. Corrected the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate routes the [same way the link view does](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing-views/lib/views/link.js#L404) by accessing the router:

```
App.Router.router.generate('book.edit', aBookInstance) # => '/books/12/edit'
```

You didn’t give the context of your application or where this request is happening. If you’re using Ember CLI and this is within a controller, for instance, you’ll have to look up the router with something like this:

```
@get('container').lookup('router:main')
```

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't answer the question, some might find it useful. A way of getting a simple `show` url to an object from the controller would be the following:

```
adapter = this.store.adapterFor('application')
adapter.buildURL('book', @get('id')) // => '/books/12
```